# DotNetOpenAuth token response

Tags: .net, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth

I have been using DotNetOpenAuth to create my own resource server. Everything works, I can retrieve tokens fine. However, I am now starting to build a client that calls my resource server and have a small problem with the response returned by DotNetOpenAuth. I expected DotNetOpenAuth to return a JSON string representing the access token. It does this, but with a small caveat: the JSON string is prefixed by a hexadecimal number and postfixed with a zero:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 4.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcUGVyc29vbmxpamtlIHByb2plY3RlblxpY2hlY2ttb3ZpZXMtZG90bmV0XHNyY1xXZWJBcGlcdG9rZW5zXA==?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 04 Mar 2013 13:04:12 GMT

3d2
{"access_token":"gAAAADrFpM2DRiBdqVBPdEq_ISvdfZb6CaRMZr7vWcn2AuKGs2TXyNlzLaUX8xtLQfxFdbTYBIK-LF8cfEwvV8gUKC0lpcodb9OWm9sUmu_IIApmMPIBQDgT1LtkEjOsv_gQdmwN906Pd1KczI2O3Pt1DqzhL_Rpub9zJQmh6EKDp4_EJAEAAIAAAACTvB0tYmrRNExdGQhGBrHgYnlgt7Rw-ilB2wLScW1YgOHE6MOY0WrfKG9aFLUAcmADYSrX55n9mfC9NKDXJBARc5ev-hnWTnApw7yq51c1KwbKv7bxoEVzar8eAAFrJi_OBQjlcaN8IFfnryu1VK_C1o-U2gLgdnBZzFcCDhgNseRFjUCmYXssEvjUswg0Oy3c_F_IXpP85kL6QCYmpGwV1juTuiMwMuZOCbcPMAssM70JMi7Ai7zT7hxCCZ5SLgeyLjBqPX7bXnhRIO24mkZ9pN5pCzorjOX_8rqdrPwR6WkPy0tc69oyBTak8L6nJYWzxfuAVhZGEowHCx3KNWfG_R_w23N7Y3c9HoIfO6RSYpnfieGLKhxHxd1_jsczGtM","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":3600,"refresh_token":"q5NN!IAAAANCHUJ5tukpT_UzgkRGCTM4Oy1qgw8GP5wn8HDS2jN1isQAAAAFfLe6KZMht1mmbIbF6RihvMZvjrwtaoZRZbaavPbte9CtjLWB_isHOroLv669rq1PmTppmVyo1Om3HVvp2AC16SDe7l02POHIYbPs_Cox6kekHc74_8pLP8SAGcrXy1EzjAPKc_UksMTp8aqaAnrU3ulx2TYYrRMyYb6pW7awO6_aiHtLixrF6dVA1-6DWvKuCSeJW0oZCm45Op1-wht8qAWkK3B70C6dZU6dmsggleA","scope":"movie list user comment"}
0
```

If I look at the official spec (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-31#section-4.1.4), it says nothing about and prefix and/or postfix. Is the output correct, or is this a bug in DotNetOpenAuth? One thing that struck me about the response that there was no `Content-length` header. This led me to believe that perhaps the `3d2` string was actually the content length. I believe this is so, as 3d2 in hex is 978 in decimal, which is precisely the length of the JSON string between 3d2 and 0.

Is there any way I could configure DotNetOpenAuth to return a regular Content-length header and not output the pre- and postfix?

To be complete, I run my authorization server in an ASP.NET MVC 4 application on .NET 4.0 using the following code (which uses dependency-injection):

```
public sealed class TokensController : Controller
{
    private readonly AuthorizationServer authorizationServer;

    public TokensController(AuthorizationServer authorizationServer)
    {
        this.authorizationServer = authorizationServer;
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var outgoingWebResponse = this.authorizationServer.HandleTokenRequest(this.Request);
        var asActionResult = outgoingWebResponse.AsActionResult();
        return asActionResult;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the DotNetOpenAuth library, where the `Content-length` header was not sent along with the request. That caused the addition of the hexadecimal number denoting the request length. After reporting this bug, it has been fixed by the author of the DotNetOpenAuth library.